# Ruby 1.9.1 Load Path Craziness

Tags: ruby, rubygems, prawn

Ok, I've just spent the 4 hours trying to figure this one out without success.  I've tried all the usual suspects and googled every combination of ruby 1.9.1, load path, gems, mac os x,freebsd,prawn and other stuff.  The bottom line is this:

When I compile ruby1.9.1-p129 from sources on mac os x 10.5, the default load path ($:) I get is:

```
ruby -e "puts $:"
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0
.
```

when I install the prawn gem, for example, I get:

```
gem which prawn
(checking gem prawn-0.5.0.1 for prawn)
/prawn.rb
```

and when I try to require it I get:

```
ruby -e "require 'prawn'"
-e:1:in `require': no such file to load -- prawn (LoadError)
    from -e:1:in `'
```

The only way I've been able to resolve this is by doing something stupid like this:

```
$: << "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/prawn-0.5.0.1/lib"
```

which, of course, is utterly ridiculous. So the question is how do I get ruby 1.9.1 to recognize and follow the correct gems path?  I've never had this issue with 1.8.7 so I'm assuming it 1.9.1 specific.  I feel I'm missing something  completely obvious here and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As an update to this question, [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) is rapidly becoming the favored way to install additional Rubies on Mac OS and Linux, by a large number of developers. Scroll to the bottom of that page and read the "Installation" and "Ruby Gems" pages before installing RVM. After installing it use `rvm notes` to find out what dependencies you'll need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

setting GEM_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

solved the problem.  I knew it was something simple.  Just aggravates me that it took ALL DAY to figure out!!  This is due to never having this issue with 1.8.7 and of course NOT RTFM!!

Answer (score 3):

same problem on kubuntu karmic.

installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential ruby1.9.1-full libsqlite3 libsqlite3-dev rubygems1.9
$ sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby rails thin --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

result:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'rubygems'; require 'sqlite3'" 
-e:1:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

solution:

```
$ export GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby1.9.1/gems/1.9.1/
```

Answer (score 2):

Next time you have such an issue, don't forget to run `gem env` from the command line. This is what happens on Windows, but the principle is much the same:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\a.grimm>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.1 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 378) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby19/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Documents and Settings/a.grimm/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'prawn'
```

Unless things have changed in 1.9 that you no longer need to require rubygems first.

Comment: ruby 1.9 no longer requires (pun intended) rubygems but just to be thorough I tried that as well without success

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a different answer to the same problem.  In some situations (ie. system start up tasks) setting environment variables before ruby runs is impossible.

Is there some way in running ruby (v >= 1.9.1) code to require gems? Without setting GEM_PATH?

Comment: As stated in the original question you can push the required gem path to $:

Comment: The "solution" was: Gem.activate('gem_name'); require('gem_name');  Notably this GEM_PATH issue goes away with 1.9.2.